# How to execute a callable task asynchronously on a separate thread using without using Threadpool Executors?

Tags: multithreading, rx-java

I need to execute a callable task on a separate thread and perform a processing action without using Threadpool Executors. Below is the solution that worked for me using RxJava. Hope this helps someone out there. If you have any suggestion or a different solution, please feel free to answer it below.

```
@Component
public class TaskProcessor<T> {


    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface ProcessResult<V> {
            void process(V v);
    }


    public  void runTaskOnNewThread(Callable<T> task,ProcessResult<T> action) {
            Assert.notNull(task, "task cannot be null");

             Observable.fromCallable(task)
                             .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                             .subscribe(new Action1<T>() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void call(T result) {
                                         action.process(result);

                                    }
                            });

    }

}
```

Comment: Recommended: You can ask and answer your own question. While posting the question, click on checkbox - **Answer your own question** -  https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: There is always a thread pool; you just don't have to manage it.

Comment: @akarnokd you are right, we didnt want to manage the pool size and other dependencies.

Comment: @PavanKumar thanks! will do it next time.

Answer (score 0):

```
(new Thread(()-> {action.process(task.call())}).start();
```